# Expected expression before { in case...switch

Tags: c, switch-statement

So I have the following:

```
//at file scope
GLfloat point_colour[3] = {1.0, 0.5, 0.0};
...

void menu_colour(int index){
  switch(index){
    case RED: point_colour = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0}; break;
    case GREEN: point_colour = {0.0, 1.0, 0.0}; break;
    case BLUE: point_colour = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0}; break;
    case ORANGE: point_colour = {1.0, 0.5, 0.0}; break;
    case PURPLE: point_colour = {1.0, 0.0, 0.8}; break;
    default: point_colour = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
  }
}
```

But I get `error: expected expression before '{' token` for every case line.

I'm trying to assign a new array of values to the `point_colour` array - any help? I suspect I'm doing it entirely the wrong way...

Comment: Initializer lists only work for initialization.

Comment: I could do it with `point_colour[0] = 1.0; blah blah` but it's really long-handed - is there no way to do it more concisely?

Comment: Perhaps a function that takes the array to fill and the values to fill it with. Something [like this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/54355162acc91586a9149f3b69bbd7a2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this in C:

```
point_colour = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0};
```

You can only do the `= {1.0, 0.5, 0.0}` at the initialization of the object. Arrays are second class citizen in C and you cannot assign to an array.

What you can do is assign a value to each element of the array individually.

If `point_colour` was a pointer, you could use a compound literal:

```
GLfloat *point_colour;

point_colour = (GLfloat []) {1.0, 0.5, 0.0};
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there no more concise way of doing it?

Comment: have an array of colours and values and memmove?

Comment: @xiaomao You can make an array of arrays, indexed by `index` and then use e.g. `memcpy` to copy the data, something like `memcpy(point_colour, colours[index], sizeof(colours[index]));`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, that's what my last suggestion is about. I'd say that the thing to do is to think.